# How do I reuse HTML User Interface elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="addFieldUI" style="display: none">
<div>
    Field Name:
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    Field Value
</div>
<div>
    Data Type:
    <select>
        <option>Price</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I would like to reuse the HTML in at least two other jQuery modals. If I use `$('#otherElem').html($('#addFieldUI').html())` to insert the HTML into an HTML element I have the problem of duplicate elements if I use input ids for the fields. Should I rather use input names? Should I use a 'script' code block instead of a div? How do I create reusable HTML?

EDIT
I am aware of jQuery data templates but in this case I just want to reuse HTML within MODAL dialogs. E.g. if I used the same form for creating and editing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
var counter = 0;
$('#otherElem').html(
    $('#addFieldUI')
        .clone()
        .attr('id', 'addFieldUI-' + counter++)
        .html()
);
```

Comment: with this approach I guess I could use the length of a JSON object as the counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a class name as a hook, and than before appending to the other div use Js to dynamically add IDs

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called **[jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)** and you can always give that a go, I used often in ASP.NET MVC, but works everywhere.

in Git you have [some demos](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/tree/master/demos)

example:

```
<script id="movieTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <li>
        <b>${Name}</b> (${ReleaseYear})
    </li>
</script>

<ul id="movieList"></ul>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var movies = [
        { Name: "The Red Violin", ReleaseYear: "1998" },
        { Name: "Eyes Wide Shut", ReleaseYear: "1999" },
        { Name: "The Inheritance", ReleaseYear: "1976" }
    ];

    $( "#movieTemplate" ).tmpl( movies ).appendTo( "#movieList" );

</script>
```

Comment: I am aware of jquery data templates, I use them all the time, but I specifically just wanted to reuse the HTML in a few modals, without any databinding.I'll update the question and be more clear.